# Change minimum size of a window?

Tags: 14.04, window

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and facing a very wierd problem. While working with Sublime text 3, sometimes when I'm resizing the window, Ubuntu would resize it to absolute zero size.

It becomes so difficult to find the window again, sure I can maximize it by using keyboard shortcut, but the moment I try to move it, it again goes back to zero.

Here you can see some examples:

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

The black line you're seeing is actually sublime text.

Any workaround for this?

Comment: Very annoying. Just had the same in 16.04 with LibreOffice Calc. I thought my window disappeared, but nope it was 1 by 30 pixels.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can change the min. window size in regards to resizing. That is up to the app to do & in the case of sublime it doesn't. Altering this is done in source & as sublime is closed source your best bet is to file a bug with them.

From xwininfo -

`Normal window size hints:
      Program supplied location: 0, 0
      Program supplied minimum size: 0 by 0`

Comment: Maybe it's different on tiling window managers, but on i3 I can force any window to 1x1 in tiling mode or to 1x1 in floating mode via `wmctrl`.