# Some windows are too small by default

Tags: window

[image: Window Too Small]

This is libre office. It's barely visible.

Is this a bug? If not how can I force minimum width and height on all windows?

Comment: Can you resize the window? If you close and restart the application after that, does it still open this tiny window or default to the last size it had?

Comment: yes you can resize it if you can find it hehe X) every time I open libre office it's that tiny, other apps don't do this by default but you can resize them to look like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to change the default size (see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/621133/change-minimum-size-of-a-window). You can focus the windows with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd> and use the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>super</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd> shortcut to maximise it.

Comment: so it's a duplicate then heh

Comment: It is indeed, but the other question has no selected answer so this one can not be marked as duplicate.